# Problemas con join

Tags: java, hibernate, join

> Tengo estas clases con sus propiedades:
>
> Turno: id, cliente, fecha.
>
> Cliente: id, tipoCliente, nombre.
>
> TipoCliente: id, descripcion.
>
> Relaciones:
>
> un Cliente muchos Turnos.
>
> un TipoCliente muchos Clientes.

Así de sencillo, está todo bien mapeado (**xml**), pero no sé usar el **join** en hql.

Quiero pedir turnos cuyo cliente sea de un determinado tipo de cliente.
Ej.: dame turnos cuyos clientes sean del tipo obra social x (pasándole el id).

**Muestro consulta equivalente(me devuelve resultado esperado) pero con subconsulta:**

```
Query q=session.createQuery("from Turno t where t.cliente in
(select c.idCliente from Cliente c where c.tipoCliente="+idTipoClien+")");
```

**Ahora muestro consulta con join que me da error:**

```
Query q=session.createQuery("from Turno t "
                + "join Cliente c "
                + "join TipoCliente tc "
                + "where tc.id="+idTipoClien);
```

Error que lanza:

```
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Path expected for join!
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Path expected for join!
```

a continuación muestra pila y luego:

```
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Invalid path: 'tc.id'
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Invalid path: 'tc.id'
 Invalid path: 'tc.id'
```

otra pila y luego:

```
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
```

otra.. y luego:

```
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
nov 28, 2019 6:14:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
 left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
```

Sé que en hql existe la unión implícita, que se puede ir navegando por las propiedades, por ej.: `c.tipoCliente.id`, que me parece fantástica pero creo que para ello hay que tener una colección en cada entidad, por ej.: en Cliente tener un `Set` o `HashSet` de turnos, pero yo no tengo nada de eso, así que supongo que descarto la forma implícita.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer el JOIN te esta faltando decirle cual es el atributo con el que se hará el JOIN quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
 Query q=session.createQuery("from Turno t "
                + "join Cliente c ON (c.id = t.id) "
                + "join TipoCliente tc ON (tc.id = c.id )"
                + "where tc.id="+idTipoClien);
```

aunque al parecer estas concatenando el parámetro dinámico, lo mas recomendable es usar algo parecido a esto:

```
Query q=session.createQuery("from Turno t "
            + "join Cliente c ON (c.id = t.id) "
            + "join TipoCliente tc ON (tc.id = c.id )"
            + "where tc.id =:idTipoClien ");
q.setParameter("idTipoClien", idTipoClien);
```

Comment: Hola, si, me faltó indicar atributo, hace mucho que lo publiqué, pero en hql no hace falta el ON e igualar llaves, o sea que es asi: `from Turno t join t.cliente c join c.tipoCliente tc where tc.id="+idTipoClien`.